# Преобразовать строку в массив

Tags: php

Всем привет! Уважаемое сообщество, помогите, пожалуйста, преобразовать строку в массив.

*Строка вот такого вида (сделал переносы для удобочитаемости):*

```
[
    {
        "charsetinfo": {
            "name": "utf-8"
        }
    },  
    {
        "value": 
            [
                {
                    "id": 1, 
                    "secid": "test", 
                    "name": "TEST"
                    },
                {
                    "id": n, 
                    "secid": "test", 
                    "name": "TEST", 
                    }
            ]
    }
]
```

*Массив нужен только вот этого куска:*

```
"id": 1, 
"secid": "test", 
"name": "TEST"
```

Чтобы примерно получилось следующего вида:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [secid] => test
    [name] => TEST
)
```

Comment: @archi_sova, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Вопрос не относиться к учебному заданию!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ЕМНИП это json, тогда так:

```
$tmpArr = json_decode($yourString);
$tmpArr = $tmpArr['value'];

foreach ( $tmpArr as $val ) {
    print_r( $val );
}
```

Comment: @thunder то вы говорите о том, что за человека делать неправильно, то даете ему готовое решение. Странный вы)

Comment: @lampa это не он был, не буду озвучивать кто! но и вам спасибо! С другой стороны, ничего зазорного и портящего репутацию в этом нету, помощь всегда должна быть, мы же не деньгою помогаем, а знаниями делимся, в ответ получаем уважение других и заслуживаем их внимания!

Comment: @archi_sova да что я, не помню чтоль?) http://hashcode.ru/questions/159538/php-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F внизу самом.

Comment: @lampa да, я такой неопределенный, но там я имел ввиду, что ЛУЧШЕ не делать за других их работу, направить -- да))) в том вопросе были нюансы о которых гадать можно было долго, это раз. во вторых в том вопросе нужно много чего было сделать с точки зрения безопасности и количества символов, отведенных в комментарии тупо не хватило бы, это два. Ваш ответ тут можно было бы лучше дополнить ссылкой на описание функции)))

Comment: Друзья, спасибо за оказанную помощь вы мне очень помогли! ;)

Comment: та не за что) но лучше гуглить и самообучаться, полезнее в итоге будет)