# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php

Всем, привет! Народ в продолжение вот [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159653/php-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) темы, опираясь на советы отвечающих, каким то чудом я все таки получил примерно то что мне надо:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [charsetinfo] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => utf-8
                )
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [secid] => test
                            [name] => TEST
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [secid] => test
                            [name] => TEST
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

но за каким-то... появляется некий *stdClass Object* и вроде как из-за этого вываливается

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type
>   stdClass as array in
>   C:\webserver\www.test.ru\www\index.php
>   on line 124

Обращаюсь к элементам массива вот таким вот образом:

```
$tmpArr = json_decode(file_get_contents($myString));
$value = $tmpArr[1]['securities'][0]['secid']; // вот эта line 124
echo $nick;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ой, я забыыыыл)))

```
$tmpArr = json_decode(file_get_contents($myString), true);
```

все же почитайте про json_decode ;)

Comment: Хаааааа! :) Теперь другое дело, спасибо!

Comment: mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )

 `assoc`  
    Если `TRUE`, возвращаемые объекты будут преобразованы в ассоциативные массивы.